# Fix Windows boot order

Tags: windows-7, boot, multi-boot

I have Windows XP, and I installed Windows 7 to my D: partition. In Windows 7 I changed the timeout to 0 and default to 'Windows XP' from bcdedit. Now I can't see the OS selection at my startup. It always loads Windows XP. How can I solve this? Can I edit bcdedit.exe from Windows XP?

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to edit the BCD with [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1).

It will let you change your boot order to whatever you like, but with a nice GUI around it.

[image]

Comment: You know what, I'll upvote your answer ;-)

Comment: "Great minds think alike" :-) . Thanks!

Comment: I decided to delete mine and just add my things with yours, makes it easier to decide who to upvote ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If **EasyBCD** doesn't work, insert the Windows 7 DVD and repair the bootloader. You can find out how to do that [here](https://superuser.com/questions/25728/how-to-fix-windows-7-boot-process).

Answer (score 1):

Am I wrong? Can't you change these settings by going to msconfig? Or am I not understanding the question?

Go to run and type MSCONFIG and click on the boot tab. There you can change the boot timeout and default OS

Answer (score 0):

You have no need to use any external software for setting up for default boot ..

```
Go to System properties -> Advance System Settings -> Startup & Recovery.
```

See the Screen of my OS. I have installed Win2k3 Server and Win7 on my laptop.
[image]

just select your default OS that you want to start. and change the timeout time below this.
you can use 5 or 10 seconds for this. may be enough to select an operating system to select from the list..