# Need handholding with BCDEDIT modifications

Tags: windows-7, boot, upgrade, bcd, bcdedit

Just upgraded my Win7-32 computer by adding a new hard drive, new memory and a new installation of Win7-64. The Win7-32 installation still exists and *was* on the C:\ drive but now from the Win7-64 installation's perspective its on the G:\ drive.

So far so good.

What I need to achieve is a boot menu that allows me to select Windows 7-64 or Windows 7-32. Both installations are on different physical hard drives and when activated, the root of each should launch on the C:\ drive.

I'm not quite sure how to change BCD entries to indicate the different devices. I think I might need to be able to indicate a "partition" in the Boot Loader section, but by default it seems to want a Volume/Drive letter. I don't want Windows7-32 coming up with the root partition on the G:\ drive!

Apologies if this question is a little vaguely worded - I'm struggling with the best way to describe the problem.

Comment: have you tried easybcd? its a pretty powerful, might do what you need. http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/

Comment: That's the best solution, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I could not have altered my boot settings without [BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net/)

The built-in BCD editor seems very tricky, (especially in Windows 8).

Comment: ([new site](http://www.boyans.net/)) This reveals quite a few BCD objects that are visible in the registry but never come up in `bcdedit.exe` nor EasyBCD - especially the Recovery Environment. [It was invaluable for me in fixing a corrupted Recovery Environment boot entry.](http://superuser.com/q/421467/117590)