# HP Recovery partition not accessable after repartitioning

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, gparted, clonezilla, bcd

I have HP Laptop that came with preinstalled Win 7. It actually had 4 primary partitions:

- 200 MB System partition that is not visible in Windows
- C: partition
- HP_Recovery partition of about 15 GB
- HP_Tools partition of about 5 GB

I wanted to add additional D: partition for data, which was not possible since all existing partitions were primary. What I did was:

1. Made an image of HP_Tools partition with Clonezilla
2. Deleted **HP_Tools** partition with GParted
3. Created new Extended partition with GParted
4. Copied existing Primary partition **HP_Recovery** inside Extended partition, thus creating a new Logical partition (again with GParted)
5. I deleted original Primary partition **HP_Recovery** with GParted
6. I created 6GB empty Logical partition **HP_Tools** with GParted
7. I created partition **D:** and arranged sizes in GParted

I rebooted into Windows, there was a standard CHKDSK screen, after which Win 7 booted w/o problems.

However, when I tried starting **Repair Your Computer** at the startup menu, and I got the **0xc0000225** Error code and a message:
*The selected entry could not be loaded because the application is missing or corrupt.*

I tried this solution: [Using GParted to Resize Your Windows 7 or Vista Partition](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-gparted-to-resize-your-windows-vista-partition/), no success.

I also tried solving the problem with BCDEasy, manually pointing to *.wim file. But with BCDEasy I can only add a new entry (there's no entry for **Repair Your Computer** option). Either way, when I try this solution I get 0xc0000017 Error:
*Ramdisk device creation failed due to insufficient memory*

Anyone have an idea? I'm refusing to give up :) since I believe I only need to point to the correct disk/file to get this working. But I just don't see how.

Comment: Not quite the same, but I've asked a [similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/421467/how-can-i-repair-or-install-startup-repair-system-recovery-after-bcd-corruption). I've also asked this over at [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/fix-boot-entry-ofinstall-startup-repairsystem/6424eada-40b7-440e-9759-e2cc67aa3e3a). So far I've concluded I'll have to manually edit the BCD in some way. I wish you luck!

Comment: I should also point out that `Repair Your Computer` is a Windows thing ([WinRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Recovery_Environment)), not a HP thing. It sits in `C:\Recovery\ `, where `C:` is the OS partition containing `\Windows`. on my HP laptop too. I think the HP Tools is accessible through the BIOS menu, containing some debugging tools, and HP Recovery would be to restore your computer to the original HP image.

Comment: You changed the HP custom MBR when you edited the partitions, not sure if you can recover that function since it is part of the MBR. Not a big deal (you can also delete the first partition named "system"), you can repair your computer by booting from a W7 install DVD or make a System Repair disc, not as convenient but provides the same tools except for HP recovery which can be accomplished another way....http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02058933&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @Bob, I'm not sure this is the case with my laptop. I have a hidden C:\Recovery folder, but it's empty. I can see HP_Recovery partition in Windows and there I can find some *.wim files. For instance E:\Recovery\WindowsRE\winre.wim 160MB file is there.

Comment: @imagodei Well, the only WinRE installation documentation I could find indicates it's done by the OEM. So it's entirely possible HP built their own image that puts the WinRE images onto their own recovery partition. I don't feel like breaking my HP laptop by repartitioning to verify, but if you want me to get any default values feel free to ask.

Comment: :) I agree, you shouldn't break your laptop. I'd like to ask you for default values, tho - you were probably thinking of BCD entries?

Comment: My laptop is HP ProBook 4530s - if that helps in any way...

Comment: @imagodei I did fix my own BCD problems just now, perhaps you can use the same method to verify? See [here](http://superuser.com/a/425962/117590).

Comment: @imagodei Also, for the record, [you must use `@Bob` or I won't be notified of your reply](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019).

Comment: @Bob, you should write an answer, linking to your solution, so I can award you with the correct answer ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here. You could create a new boot entry, with the correct options for the boot entry (in particular, `WinPEMode` and `RecoveryOS`). Alternatively, you could fix your existing boot entry to point to the correct location.

Most BCD editing tools don't show the recovery entries for whatever reason. It *is* possible to edit those entries through the registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\BCD00000000\Objects\`), but that could get confusing quite quickly. [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net/) does display recovery entries, among others, in a friendly view.

I've personally gone through a similar process, and have more detailed steps [here](https://superuser.com/a/425962/117590). You could either fix the existing entries as I did, or add a new entry with the correct options as seen in the screenshots on the linked answer. <sup>I have not tested adding a new entry, and am unsure if it will work or not.</sup>

**Likely differences from the solution in that answer are as follows:**

The first thing to do is make sure you edit the recovery entry the main OS entry's `RecoverySequence` points to. This is the one that will be loaded on startup.

The `ApplicationDevice` and `OSDevice` options must point to the location of the Windows Recovery Environment's image (`.wim`). For me, this is a `169,213,970 byte` file called `Winre.wim`. Since you shuffled the partitions, it's likely the path is already there but the drive letter is missing. You must identify which partition contains the appropriate path and files. On a normal Windows installation, this is the main OS drive (`C:`).

> I can see HP_Recovery partition in Windows and there I can find some *.wim files. For instance E:\Recovery\WindowsRE\winre.wim 160MB file is there.

That is likely the correct image. In your case, those options should have the drive letter set to `E:`.

**I'm not sure WinRE can be loaded from a logical/extended partition.** It's worth a try, otherwise you should probably restore the recovery partition back to a primary one. Or you could even try copying the image into the main OS partition. The worst that should happen is a failure to boot into the RE.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on SuperUser yet, so I'm leaving an answer (sorry), though I'm not convinced this will fix it.

What about something like TestDisk - it searches for lost partitions and can rewrite the partition table to include them. I've never tried it for a boot partition before, but I have recovered NTFS and FAT partitions that had otherwise been deleted this way. TestDisk is free at http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk