# Windows boot with F8: No system repair - how to get it back?

Tags: windows, restore

Normally, when Starting Windows (7) and Pressing F8 there comes a menu where is something like:

```
Start in Safe Mode
Safe mode with command prompt
...
System Repair
```

The System Repair is not available on my Win 7 X64 Pro.
How do I get it back?

I have System Check Points disabled, is it because of this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for "Repair Your Computer", and that only exists if the [Windows Recovery Environment](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc765966(v=ws.10).aspx) (or perhaps an OEM recovery system replacement) was included during the initial install of Windows.

[image]

From [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/advanced-startup-options-including-safe-mode#1TC=windows-7):

> Shows a list of system recovery tools you can use to repair startup
>   problems, run diagnostics, or restore your system. *This option is
>   available only if the tools are installed on your computer's hard
>   disk*. If you have a Windows installation disc, the system recovery
>   tools are located on that disc.

More info on SU: [How do you recreate the System Recovery environment in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/55585/how-do-you-recreate-the-system-recovery-environment-in-windows-7)

Perhaps check out this MSDN Blog: [How to install Windows RE on the hard disk](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winre/archive/2007/01/12/how-to-install-winre-on-the-hard-disk.aspx).

Alternatively, to access the tools, make a "System Repair Disk" or boot from your Windows 7 install media.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these options allow you to go back to a previous system restore point. If you have disabled System Restore points, you will not be able to restore to a last known configuration or earlier restore point either, and thus these options are missing.